# How to get two different imageview in Recyclerview row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

how do i get two different imageview and textviews in each row of recyclerview 
and i want to make each imageview clickable .... i have done this in list view but don't know how to do it in recycler view .... so help me to acheive this ... thanks in advance

here is my layout file recyclerview row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_title_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/category_title_one"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_title_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dp">

        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_price2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/category_title_two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="10dp">

        </TextView>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my adapterclass

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
public ImageLoader mImageLoader;

//List of superHeroes
List<ListOfData> superHeroes;

public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(List<ListOfData> superHeroes, Context context) {
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.superHeroes = superHeroes;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListOfData superHero = superHeroes.get(position);

    mImageLoader = MyApplication.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView1, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    mImageLoader.get(superHero.getImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.imageView2, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));

    holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.imageView2.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
    holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
    holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
    //holder.textViewRank.setText(String.valueOf(superHero.getRank()));
    //holder.textViewRealName.setText(superHero.getRealName());
    //holder.textViewCreatedBy.setText(superHero.getCreatedBy());
    //holder.textViewFirstAppearance.setText(superHero.getFirstAppearance());

    String powers = "";

   /* for(int i = 0; i<superHero.getPowers().size(); i++){
        powers+= superHero.getPowers().get(i);
    }*/

    //holder.textViewPowers.setText(powers);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return superHeroes.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public NetworkImageView imageView1;
    public NetworkImageView imageView2;
    public TextView textViewName1;
    public TextView textViewName2;
    public TextView textViewRank;
    public TextView textViewRealName;
    public TextView textViewCreatedBy;
    public TextView textViewFirstAppearance;
    public TextView textViewPowers;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView1 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        imageView2 = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail2);
        textViewName1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_one);
        textViewName2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_two);
        /* textViewRank= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRank);
        textViewRealName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRealName);
        textViewCreatedBy= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCreatedBy);
        textViewFirstAppearance= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFirstAppearance);
        textViewPowers= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPowers);
        */
    }
}
```

}

here is Json part

```
public class Pants extends Fragment {

//Creating a List of superheroes

public Context context;
public List<ListOfData> listSuperHeroes;

//Creating Views
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;


public Pants() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tshirts_pants_shirts, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    //Calling method to get data
    getData();
    return view;
}


private void getData() {
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    //Creating a json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(ProductConfig.DATA_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

//This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        ListOfData superHero = new ListOfData();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
            superHero.setName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_NAME));
            /*superHero.setRank(json.getInt(ProductConfig.TAG_RANK));
            superHero.setRealName(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_REAL_NAME));
            superHero.setCreatedBy(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_CREATED_BY));
            superHero.setFirstAppearance(json.getString(ProductConfig.TAG_FIRST_APPEARANCE));
            */

            ArrayList<String> powers = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(ProductConfig.TAG_POWERS);

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                powers.add(((String) jsonArray.get(j)) + "\n");
            }
            superHero.setPowers(powers);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }
    adapter = new RecyclerViewDataAdapter(listSuperHeroes, context);

    //Adding adapter to recyclerview
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //Initializing our superheroes list



}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific. What issue are you facing. Is one image not visible? Is the row item missing all together? ....

Comment: getting same images in both imageview in each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the images of the same row belong to the same hero or are they from different heroes?

If they are from different heroes:

1) Change your recyclerview row layout to have only 1 imageview and 2 textviews (remove the second relativelayout)

2) Change the LayoutManager of your recyclerview to GridLayoutManager with 2 columns:

```
    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return 2;
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

3) Change your onBindViewHolder meethod and ViewHolder class accordingly (remove the second imageview and the third and fourth textviews)

4) Make the image clickable adding the following to the onBindViewHolder method:

```
        holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: i've done what you said but now i have only image images in row and its taking all the width in row

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, in `onBindViewHolder` you're setting both of your `TextViews` and `ImageViews` using the same data.  Which is why you're getting the same image twice. What you should do is pass `Map<int, List<Object>> superHeroes` into your `RecyclerView`. The key would be the row item number and the list would contain objects for both your superheroes with a title and image uri.

To make your individual ImageViewsclickable`, set an`onClickListener`on each`onBindViewHolder` and handle their respect logic.

Answer (score 0):

From this code I can see that you set the same image to imageView1 and imageView2 and the same text for textViewName1 and textViewName2

```
 holder.imageView1.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
 holder.imageView2.setImageUrl(superHero.getImageUrl(), mImageLoader);
 holder.textViewName1.setText(superHero.getName());
 holder.textViewName2.setText(superHero.getName());
```

If you would like to have two different images, you have to set two different images and not the same one.

For the click handling you have to set the onClickListener on the image/text/button/view that you want making clickable, for example if you want that your imageView1 is clickable you have to do

```
 holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

than you have to implements the interface

```
public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
```

and after that you can handle the onClick event in the overrided method

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

 }
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the question is 4 years old. I going to post an answer so other people can see it.

Since you are providing an array, the position is getting the values ( image and text) item from each index of the array.

What you need to do is provide the array as you did but make sure each index of the array contain image1, text1, image2 and text2.